# Можно ли определить, является ли последовательность 2х байтов печатными символами?

Tags: c#, unicode, ресурсы

Формат файла из которого я хочу вычитать данные `.res`, но это не обычный файл ресурсов, а что-то похожее на упакованные строки, в кодировке `UTF16-LE`.

Проблем с чтением такого файла не возникает, но когда я его считываю, вижу что между строками, находится какая-то информация *(скорее это похоже на маппинг идентификаторов предложений)*. И если его читать прямо, то  получается какая-то белиберда. И в некоторых случаях, текст преобразуется из нормального, т.е. Английского в смесь китайского с английским.

Ниже представлю часть текста, но он не совсем верен в таком виде, поэтому если потребуется, приложу ссылку на один из ресурсов.

```
§   ‡ & A h !   W h y   d i d   I   w a n t   t o   b e c o m e   a   d o c t o r ? ‡ 1 B e c a u s e   I   w a n t e d   t o   h e l p   p e o p l e ,   o b v i o u s l y !   H e h e ! ‡ - M u m m y !   M u m m y !   I   d i d   i t !   I   e v e n   g o t   t o p   m a r k
```

Можно ли определить является ли символ `utf16-le` или последовательность из 2х байт `utf8`, печатным символом?

[Файл ресурса](https://mega.nz/#!BcxEjIQZ!0ljL28oR2evklh7HdZMljR5cx9StJeb7Om9rVAcGvn4)

Вот так выглядит файл при открытии его в нужной кодировке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше бы выяснить формат. Навскидку там возможно записана длина строки. И лучше бы показать hexdump файла или даже сам файл выложить

Comment: Файл добавил, но там целых 10 байт от начала строки идет, думаю что там не длина хранится.

Comment: Ну длина там точно есть. она стоит перед самой строкой. занимает либо 1 байт, либо 2 в big endian. остальные байты надо смотреть ...

Comment: смотрю остальные строки. там всегда 6 байт между строк. Из них 2 известны - длина. Значит перед ними еще 4 что то значащие. А в начале файла к ним добавлено еще 3 байта - считаем заголовком файла

Comment: @Mike: Вы просто гений! Получилось считать чистую строку!!!

Comment: @Mike, Вы все правильно сказали, 4 байта - ID строки, 2 байта - длина, будьте так любезны, добавьте ваши комментарии ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В любых двоичных файлах, предназначенных для разбора программами, строки переменной длины могут быть представлены только 2-мя способами: с окончанием определенными символами (обычно 0) или с указанием длины, длина при этом в подавляющем количестве случаев записана перед самой строкой.

Если присмотреться к файлу внимательно (в виде hex дампа) можно заметить, что прямо перед каждой строкой два байта представляют собой как раз ее длину (с 16 битных символах). Перед ними еще фиксировано 4 байта представляющих некую информацию. В самом начале файла перед ними есть еще 3 байта, которые можно расценивать как заголовок файла.

Comment: Благодаря вам извлек всю информацию: https://pastebin.com/prnbkkTn `^_^`

Answer (score 1):

Определить то просто:

```
static bool IsChar(byte[] bytes)
{
    char c = (char)BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, 0);
    return Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || Char.IsPunctuation(c) || Char.IsSymbol(c);
}
```

Но я не думаю, что это поможет в чтении ресурсов, так как нетекстовое содержимое ресурсов вполне может случайно совпасть с нормальными символами. Изучите формат файла (возможно, это формат [скомпилированных ресурсов Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/resource-file-formats)) и напишите код, извлекающий из него только строки.